# Android Notification doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have read many posts on the website and I believe in order to pop up a basic notification there aren't many lines of codes need to write.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("StartUpActivity", "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_up);


    NotificationManager notiManager = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Hello")
        .setContentText("hello")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setAutoCancel(false);
    notiManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    Log.i("here", "here");

}
```

I have also tried Notification.Builder which also doesn't work. I do not know where the problem is. And as the intent / pendingintent are optional to the notification, I just didn't add the code. (Though even I add the intent the notification doesn't show up)

I have also add the permission VIBRATE in the manifest which i do not know the usage of.

I just want to know how to pop up a notification on the status bar. thanks.

Comment: Does your "here" log show up?

Comment: it seems clean, not sure try changing the id from 0 to another positive number and see if it works.

Comment: tried your code as it is and works very fine !

Comment: really? here shows ... my code works?

Comment: I AM VERY SAD. I CHANGE THE EMULATOR AND IT WORKS. MY PREVIOUS ONE WAS NEXUS 7. ANOTHER REASON NOT TO BUY IT......

Answer (score 0):

The VIBRATE permission is to allow the device the device to vibrate. You are not using this permission, you can remove it.

You need to call .build() after .setAutoCancel(false);

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version on Android (22 target sdk version) with sdk 14 compatibility you have to add a "style" to the notification to show a preview of the compact one.

For example:

```
NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.notifications_title));
bigTextStyle.bigText(messageText);
bigTextStyle.setSummaryText(getString(R.string.notification_call_to_action));
mBuilder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
```

before

```
 notifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```